# Some managed beans are not loaded

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with a perfectly working application (JSF 2, primefaces, tomcat 6). I have many Managed Beans that work just fine, but lately when I try to add a new Managed Bean the views dont seem to recognize it. Even more, there is no error message the application manages to ignore controls refering to the new managed bean and even by using debugging I don't have access to the @PostConstruct method when the view loads. this seems to be the issue for whatever control I put in my view.

Comment: Are the new managed beans CDI scoped or JSF scoped?

Comment: Could be your code not properly being deployed to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the new managed beans are in a way a copy of the old ones (in order to ensure that it is not due to a programming error) plus there is no server error the primefaces components are shown just fine and no exceptions are thrown. Managed beans are JSF Scoped